Hosting Django from a directory
My directory structure is like so:
C:\htdocs                                     # web root
   |_ django-container
      +- django-project
      |  +- core                              # startproject
      |  |_ myapp1                            # startapp
      +- public
         +- static                            # STATIC_ROOT, collectstatic
         |  +- css
         |  +- images
         |  |_ js
         |_ media                             # MEDIA_ROOT

Nginx config:
http {
  # ...
  upstream wsgi-server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
  server {
    # ...
    location /mysite/ {
      proxy_pass http://wsgi-server/;
    }
    location /mysite/public/media/ {
      alias C:/htdocs/django-container/public/media/;
      autoindex off;
    }
    location /mysite/public/static/ {
      alias C:/htdocs/django-container/public/static/;
      autoindex off;
    }
  }
}

I run a waitress WSGI server as a service on port 8000 that runs core.wsgi.application. My settings.MEDIA_URL and settings.STATIC_URL are public/media/ and public/static/ respectively.
When I do redirects in my app, or create urls in templates, it doesn't have the mysite segment, because of which all links fail. Even the public/static/ and public/media/ links. For the last 2, I could add the segment to settings.STATIC_URL and settings.MEDIA_URL, but I wanted a common way to add the mysite segment at all places, preferably automatically if possible.

I think you're best bet would be to edit the main urls.py file and prepend the mysite/ for each includes.. then just add the segment to the STATIC/MEDIA Urls in the settings..

Prepending mysite/ to core.urls wouldn't work. By the time the URL reaches Django, mysite/ segment is already resolved by Nginx (location /mysite/) and removed, only the remaining is sent to Django, so nothing would match. FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME worked.

Per Django documentation, just had to set FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/mysite' in core.settings. It worked for all redirects, URLs, Static and Media files in one shot, no other changes were required in Django.
But I have another problem now because of adding this. python manage.py runserver now fails with Page Not Found - Request URL: http://localhost:8000/mysite/mysite/account/ when on my browser address there is only http://localhost:8000/mysite/account/.
As a quick fix, I have put FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME in a yaml file that is read in settings.py. I manipulate this yaml when I want to run it with runserver or under standalone WSGI server. If anyone has a better solution that works for both, please add your answer.
